# export mailbox data from a mailbox to a .pst file (Exchange 2007)

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, export, mailbox, outlook

I want to delete some old exchange accounts. Therefore I want to backup the mails in these accounts before deleting them. I found the article [How to export mailbox data](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266964%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) from Microsoft. I want to export to a `pst`-file. I found out that I have to install `Exchange 2007 management tools` because the server is 64-bit. Now I downloaded Exchange 2007 and wanted to install the managment tool component. The problem is that my operating system (Windows 7) is not supported.

What options do I have to export the mailbox to a pst-file? Do I need a computer with Windows XP?

**EDIT**

I start the setup.exe and the only option I have is to use `Step 5: Install Microsoft Exchange Server 2007 SP2`. Than I make the custom installation and only select `Management Tools`. Than I get the following error:

[image]

It says that I use Windows 7 Professional and the Exchange Server 2007 does not support it. If I click on recommended action I will be redirected to this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/2edd2d3e-456e-431e-90c5-9219e2abad6f.aspx). On this page it again is statetd that Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 is not supported. I should use a compatible computer ...

Comment: Are you running Windows 7 64-bit?

Comment: @JeremyLyons: Windows 7 32-bit.

Comment: Did you ensure you downloaded the 32-bit version of the tools? It lists Windows 7 as a supported OS, which leads me to believe you're trying to install the 64-bit tools on 32-bit Windows 7. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11876

Comment: @JeremyLyons: The file I downloaded is called `E2K7SP2DE32.exe`. There is no option for 32 bit, but the heading and the filename says it is 32 bit. I will describe my steps in detail im my question.

Comment: Others around the web say that you can put the setup.exe file into Windows Vista compatibility mode and right-click run as administrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah ha! Forget all of the above. You need the Exchange 2007 **SP3** media, which explicitly states that it adds support for Windows 7 and 2008 R2.

http://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=24111

This is why the link I originally posted stated support for Windows 7, which I found confusing after reading the info you provided.

Comment: I had to do a few things: http://thelowedown.wordpress.com/2010/02/12/exchange-2007-exporting-mailboxes-using-windows-7/ and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd285510%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx. The command was `Export-Mailbox -Identity <MailboxIdParameter> -PSTFolderPath <Path_Of_PST_Folder>\<File_Name>.pst
-ExcludeFolders "\Junk E-Mail","\Contacts"`.